# Polymer Page.js paper-header-panel element scroll top when menu item selected

Tags: polymer, page.js

I have a problem with paper-menu and paper-header-panel. When I click on my paper-menu items and webcomponents has correctly loaded the relative page, this one appears in the previous scrolled position. How I can set to scroll on top when the click is performed??

Answer (score 2):

This is because the main container of your header panel has fixed height.
If you are using [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) all you have to do is remove the height for the ".content" class in app-theme.html

Comment: I resolved by scrolling in top programmatically in JavaScript ... I will try to remove  this property ....

Comment: I used to do that but in some cases it just didn't work, plus, the fix above is more cleaner :)